# php gd and text

Tags: php, gd

Is it possible the saved text with different styles and colors in the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to rephrase your question a bit. But if I understand you correctly, you want to know whether it is possible to render differently styled text using GD in one image.

This is possible by separating the text into multiple `ImageFTText()` commands with different fonts and colours.

It gets tricky, though, if you want one word to have different stylings, because then things like [Kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) (the correct spacing between character pairs) comes into play. You would have to use `ImageFTBBox()` to measure the size of each character (or text) to know where to continue with the next one - and even that is not guaranteed to look pretty.